# How can I make a text in an input box at the center in the vertical direction in IE7?

Tags: html, css

If firefix4 , the text in the input box is at the middle but in IE7, the text is at the top..How can I make the text align vertically at the center of the input box in IE7?

Untitled Document

```
<body>
<!-- start wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- start header -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="Login">
           <h1>User Login</h1>
           <form name="Login" method="#" action="#">
                <input type="text" value="User Name" />
                <input type="password" value="password" />
           </form>
           <div class="links"><h3>Not yet a Member?</h3> <a href="">Register Now</a> <a href="">    <span>Login</span></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End header -->

    <!-- Start main -->
    <div class="main"></div>
    <!-- End main -->

    <!-- start footer -->
    <div class="footer"></div>
    <!-- End footer -->

</div>
<!-- End wrapper -->
```

/* CSS */

```
  @charset "utf-8";
  /* CSS Document */


 /*  CSS Reset  */
ul,li,h1,h2,h3{padding:0;margin:0;}
ul{list-style:none;}


 /*  CSS for wrapper  */
.wrapper{background:#fffde4  ;width:664px;height:789px;margin:0 auto;border:#000 thin      groove;color:#bb9d59;padding:17px 28px 28px 35px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

 /* Header */
 .header{width:664px;border:#000 thin groove;overflow:hidden;}
 .Login{width:390px;border:#000 thin double;float:right;}
  h1{margin-bottom:7px;border:#000 thin groove;color:#2c787b;font-size:27px;}
 input[type="text"],input[type="password"]{width:172px;height:21px;color:#bb9d59;background-     color:#f9f6d4;border:none;font-size:10px;padding-left:9px;float:left}
 input[type="text"]{border:#000 thin groove;}
 input[type="password"]{border:#000 thin groove;margin-left:15px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2wrS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `line-height: Xpx;` where X is the height of your textbox.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use vertical-align: middle; You give the containing element a line-height then set vertical-align to the content. This example seems to "work for me:"

http://jsfiddle.net/pb4vT/2/

Good luck!

ps - looks like vertical-align is not needed, oops :)